# build a deb package for armv7ahf-vfp

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04, embedded-linux, armv7

I am trying to create a deb package for my qt project to install on my sama5d3. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. have managed to create it for armhf. but when I try to install it on the board it fail with "incompatible architecture".
so I search for the architecture and find it is armv7ahf-vfp. how can I build a package for that architecture?

Comment: The `armhf` is probably the same thing if you've made it with the compiler that comes with Debian. Copy the binary to the board and see if it works. Then repackage the deb package so it says `armv7ahf-vfp`. It's just an attribute of a deb package.

Answer (score 1):

ok I found how to build for armv7ahf-vfp.. just run the poky environment setup script :

```
source /environment-setup-cortexa5t2hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```